# Module error: Rasterio has no attribute open

Tags: python-3.x, macos, rasterio

I installed rasterio with `pip install rasterio` and tried running a simple command like `rasterio.open(path/file)` but get the following error message:

`module 'rasterio' has no attribute 'open'`

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling but to no avail. Does anyone know what causes this error and how to fix it?

For your information, I am running the command on Python 3.7 on a Mac.

Comment: same problem, did you find any solution?

Comment: What version of rasterio and pip are you using?

Answer (score -1):

Did you import rasterio?

e.g:

```
pip install rasterio
import rasterio
path = '/here/is/your/file/path.tif'
rasterio.open(path)
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please consider explaining why this might be the solution and elaborating.

Comment: Thanks! Well I had a similar "no attribute" problem with using rasterio.mask.mask(), and it was because I hadn't imported rasterio.mask module. Seems like importing rasterio library would enable the use of rasterio.open().